# cache image using angularjs without plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<img src="http://assets.example.com/static/thumb_{{selected}}.jpg"/>
```

my selected model is dynamic, I can load the img proper but how to cache every single photo because I notice there's a delay when I apply new value to `selected`.

Comment: Is your asset store under your control? You could set correct `cache-control` headers to tell the browser to cache the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do it in your controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', function(images) {
    var preload = {};
    angular.forEach(images, function(image, i) {
        preload[i] = new Image()
        preload[i].src = "http://assets.example.com/static/thumb_" + image + ".jpg";
    });
});
```

Comment: ah great, I forgot there's things call `new Image()`!!

Answer (score 1):

angular
  .module('demo', [
    'ngImageCache'
  ])
;

Note: Image is loaded using javascript, content is stored in sessionStorage for next loading

Use package npm install ng-image-cache

Comment: Part of the requirements was 'without plugin'. This seems to contradict that requirement.

Comment: If you are not using through an $http service you might use the $cacheFactory service that generates cache objects for all Angular services. Internally, the $cacheFactory creates a default cache object.

Comment: use put method: 
cache.put(key, value); & you can easily access the key by cache.get(key);

Or if you're using any $http method then

 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/dummyimages.json',
   cache: true
});